# Extracting fixed effects table output from lme object

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to fit a model which is similar to the

```
fm2orth.lm<-lme(distance~age,data=OrthoFem, random=~1|Subject)
```

and did

```
summary(fm2Orth.lm)
```

my output had these parts

1. Aic/BIC
2. Random Effects
3. Fixed Effects table
4. Correlation.

My question is I am interested in only the third output above  and tried

```
fm2Orth.lm$coefficients
```

and had coefficients of the individual subjects, which is not what I want, can someone show me how I could get only the fixed effects table with the p-values.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is quite easy:

```
summary(fm2Orth.lm)$tTable
```

will give you the full table (not just the coefficients).

In general, use:

```
names(fm2Orth.lm)
```

and

```
names(summary(fm2Orth.lm))
```

to see what objects are contained in those lists. Then you can explore those objects and you will often find what you need.

**EDIT:** Since this was raised in the comments and may be useful to some: Extracting the variances of the random effects can be tricky from the objects in those lists. See here for a way of extracting those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043565/extracting-random-effects-from-nlme-summary/9043924#9043924

Comment: +1 answer. Both `names` and `str` are very useful for poking into structures like that. Unless it's an S4 class (you use an 'foo@bar' instead of 'foo$bar' to access members), in which case you'll need `slotNames`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning `str` and the difference with S4 classes. I think the output from `str` can be confusing for a novice (especially for complex structures like those created by the `lme` function), but once you get the hang of it, it is an indispensable tool.

Comment: You're right: at first I never used `str` because of information overload, but now I find that it often saves an additional step (i.e. find a name, figure it might be of interest, then `class` or `dim` or print it to figure out what it really is).

Comment: -1 Since this leads to a dead end.  A method that works is given at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9043924/937932) using `VarCorr` but unfortunately this returns a character rather than a numeric.

Comment: What do you mean this leads to a dead end? The OP was asking about the table with the fixed effects and `summary(fm2Orth.lm)$tTable` gives just that. The link you gave shows how to get the random effects.

Comment: Apologies, my bad, I misread the OP as looking for the random effects.  However I did waste a lot of time using the "general" method to find an object for the random effects.  I can remove the downvote if you make a trivial edit.

Comment: No problem. I added the link you mentioned to my answer, since this is indeed helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The class of the output of `lme` is, not surprisingly, `lme`. You can find this by running `class(fm2orth.lm)`.

As a consequence, when you call `summary` on it, what is really called is `summary.lme`. This function is not exported from the nlme package (you can discover this when you type `summary.lme` at the prompt: you get a message that the object is not found), but you can still get to its source like this: `getAnywhere("summary.lme")`.

You will see there some of the objects of the summary are built up and what name they are given (e.g. `object$tTable <- ...`) You will also see that the result of `summary.lme` is an object of class `summary.lme` (again, no surprises there).

Finally, you can check `print.summary.lme`, because `print` is what is automatically called by R to display the return value of the last statement, but like `summary`, it is dispatched to a version that is class-specific. Note, once again, this function is not exported from the package, so you'll have to use `getAnywhere`.

Finally, in this function's source, you'll see a call `cat("Fixed effects: ")` that obviously marks the start of printing the information you're interested in. There you can see that what is really printed (`cat(deparse)`), is based upon the summary's member `call$fixed` but may depend on the way the original model was built.

This should give you enough info to find out how to get to it.

**Edit**: I just noticed that the object returned from `summary.lme` is really the orginal fit (so the return value of `lme` itself, with some extra list items added to it. As such, this `call` member used in `print.summary.lme` is already part of the original fit (, since it is not added by `summary.lme`). Result: you probably don't really need the summary to get to the fixed effects.

Comment: Hi Nick, I really enjoyed your question on this. Do you think it is possible to create a table with all the parameters that you estimate from a lmer, this is like saving in a table the fixed effects - beta values and the random effects too ?